# How to replace hover for mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, hover

I tried to use :active for the mobile device but it doesn't seem to work.  Can I do this with css or do I need to create mouseover listeners in javascript?

```css
#major{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-around;
   list-style-type:none;
}

#minor1,#minor2{
   display:none;
}

#about:hover, #take:hover{
   background-color:#538231;
   color:white;
}


#take:hover #minor2, #take:active #minor2 {
   display:flex;
   position:absolute;
   justify-content:start; 
   left:0 ;
   list-style-type:none;
   background-color:#538231;
   color:white;
   width:100%;
}

#about:hover #minor1, #about:active #minor1{
   display:flex;
   position:absolute;
   justify-content:start; 
   left:0; 
   list-style-type:none; 
   background-color:#538231;
   color:white;
   width:100%;
}

#navbar{
   position:relative;
   font-size:3.5vw;
   color:#538231;
   background-color:#b3d7f7;
}

li{
   margin:0!important;
}

#minor1 li{
   margin-left:3vw!important;
}

#minor2 li{
   margin-left:1vw!important;
   margin-right:5vw!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="major">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li id="about">ABOUT US
<ul id="minor1">
  <li>OUR STORY</li>
  <li>OUR WORK</li>
  <li>SWAG LEADERS</li>
  <li>IN THE NEWS</li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li>CALENDAR</li>
  <li id="take">TAKE ACTION
<ul id="minor2">
  <li>GET INVOLVED</li>
  <li>DONATE</li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li>RESOURCES</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can use `:focus` or use javascript.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A mobile screen has no mouse so a HOVER doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `:hover` should actually work on touch devices (at least in my mobile Safari test). I ran the code in jfiddle, and it worked. There technically isn't a hover, but if something is tapped on, it assumes it is :hover as well.

Comment: :focus doesn't work,  I'm trying to get the submenu to display when you touch the li

Comment: no, on a iphone hover does nothing

Comment: try auto prefixing your code since you're using `display flex;`

Comment: what in the world does using flex have to do with auto prefixing??

Comment: using display: flex only doesn't work with all browsers.. that's why sometimes we use -webkit- to ensure cross-browser compatibility. i'm also just suggesting it i'm not saying it's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to go on only pure HTML and CSS, I have two options for this.

First is to put an attribute `tabindex="0"` on li tag then add `:focus` selector on the css. But the problem with this is that you have to click somewhere else to display none the sub-menus.

Second is to have a checkbox to accommodate the click/unclick event. I just set an example for mobile view, @media query of max-width: 800px. So please resize the browser when you check this.

Please check my code below:

```css
#major{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-around;
   list-style-type:none;
}

#minor1,#minor2{
   display:none;
}

#about:hover, #take:hover{
   background-color:#538231;
   color:white;
}


#take:hover #minor2, #take:active #minor2 {
   display:flex;
   position:absolute;
   justify-content:start; 
   left:0 ;
   list-style-type:none;
   background-color:#538231;
   color:white;
   width:100%;
}

#about:hover #minor1, #about:active #minor1{
   display:flex;
   position:absolute;
   justify-content:start; 
   left:0; 
   list-style-type:none; 
   background-color:#538231;
   color:white;
   width:100%;
}

#navbar{
   position:relative;
   font-size:3.5vw;
   color:#538231;
   background-color:#b3d7f7;
}

li{
   margin:0!important;
}

#minor1 li{
   margin-left:3vw!important;
}

#minor2 li{
   margin-left:1vw!important;
   margin-right:5vw!important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#about input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label, #take input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  background-color:#538231;
  color:white;
}

#about input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul, #take input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
  display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  justify-content:start; 
  left:0; 
  list-style-type:none; 
  background-color:#538231;
  color:white;
  width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="major">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li id="about">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">ABOUT US</label>
<ul id="minor1">
  <li>OUR STORY</li>
  <li>OUR WORK</li>
  <li>SWAG LEADERS</li>
  <li>IN THE NEWS</li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li>CALENDAR</li>
  <li id="take">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2">
    <label for="check2">TAKE ACTION</label>
<ul id="minor2">
  <li>GET INVOLVED</li>
  <li>DONATE</li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li>RESOURCES</li>
</ul>
</div>
```